# Can I test servlet filters with REST Assured?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, rest-assured

I have a Spring Boot MVC app with a `@WebFilter` that adds a custom header to every response. It works fine when I actually run the app, but I'm a little surprised that the filter doesn't run during my REST Assured test.

There's nothing fancy in my test; it basically reduces to

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new MyController());
boolean headerExists = given().when().get().headers().hasHeaderWithName("my-header");
```

Is this expected? Should I be doing something extra to set up the filter chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MockMvc is an infrastructure to test your controllers and not the full web container.

If you want to have the filters working you have to add it.
This would look something like:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
   Collection<Filter> filterCollection = wac.getBeansOfType(Filter.class).values();
   Filter[] filters = filterCollection.toArray(new Filter[filterCollection.size()]);
   mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(filters).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I take that to mean that this is one of those times when my unit test is trying to be more of an integration test?

Comment: Yes. If you want test the web layer you should use WebTestClient or TestRestTemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as this:

```java
StandaloneMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController);
builder.addFilters(new YourFilter());
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(builder);
```